# Upgrading jQuery plugin (jquery.hammer)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, hammer.js

I hope you guys can help me in upgrading jquery.hammer js plugin. I am getting hammer related codes from http://cdnjs.com/libraries/hammer.js/ where it listed all versions of hammerJs.

I am using jquery.hammer.js (jquery plugin) v1.0.5 and I wanted to upgrade to latest version (if I am not wrong, latest version of  hammer is 2.0.4 (20/04/2015)).

My question is: where is the jquery.hammer.js for the hammer version above 1.0.6? If the jquery plugin is not required for hammer 1.0.7 and above, how can I use hammer with jQuery?

Many thanks in advance
-Vinnie

Comment: http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/

Comment: There likely isn't a jquery version anymore (which is a good thing because now it can be used in places where jQuery isn't needed as well as along side jQuery.)

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search gets [version 2](https://github.com/hammerjs/jquery.hammer.js) of jquery.hammer.js